# golang with fastcgi how to read REMOTE_USER

Tags: go, fastcgi, basic-authentication, openbsd

Short: How can I read the CGI var REMOTE_USER on golang using fastcgi?

Long:
I'm trying to write a program in go to work behind a httpd using fcgi over a socket. The httpd does the ssl termination and provides basic auth. I need to read $REMOTE_USER, but I cannot in golang, while I can in perl.

My code is based on [this fcgi example](http://www.dav-muz.net/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-go-and-fastcgi/). I try

```
func homeView(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {     
    user, pass, authok := r.BasicAuth()
```

But authok is always false, user and pass remain empty, although I know for sure that the authorization (done by httpd) was OK. To eliminate other errors, I have done it in perl:

```
my $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket("/run/fcgi-check.sock", 5);
my $q = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $socket);

while ($q->Accept() >= 0) {
    my $c = CGI::Simple->new;
    my $user_id      = $c->remote_user();
```

and it works fine in perl.

To debug, I printed the output of r.Header and I got:

```
map[Authorization:[]
```

Am I right that the header that go sees does no hold any information about any authorization? But it does in perl.

Here is a full but minimal golang code example that demonstrates the problem (on OpenBSD 5.8 with go version go1.4.2 openbsd/amd64 and OpenBSDs httpd with 'authenticate "/" with restricted_users' in httpd.conf.

```
package main

import (
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "io"
        "log"
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "net/http"
        "net/http/fcgi"
)


func homeView(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        headers := w.Header()
        headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html")
        headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
        headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")
        headers.Add("Expires", "0")
        r.ParseForm()

        user, pass, authok := r.BasicAuth()

        if authok {
                io.WriteString(w, fmt.Sprintln("Auth OK"))
                io.WriteString(w, fmt.Sprintln("user is: "+user+", pass is: "+pass))
        } else {
                io.WriteString(w, fmt.Sprintln("Auth NOT OK"))
        }
}

func main() {

        r := mux.NewRouter()
        r.HandleFunc("/check/", homeView)

    var err error
        listener, err := net.Listen("unix", "/run/fcgi-check.sock")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer listener.Close()

        err = fcgi.Serve(listener, r)
        if err != nil { log.Fatal(err)}
}
```

Help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
T.

Comment: Your perl example is using the REMOTE_USER variable, but the Go example is trying to do BasicAuth. Have you checked the request headers for "Remote-User" (I'm fairly certain the CGI variables get canonicalized and mapped to headers)? Also, why are you using FCGI at all?

Comment: I cannot find how to read the REMOTE_USER CGI environment variable in go (if `r.BasicAuth()` isn't the right way to do it). Like said in my posting I have printed the full headers using `io.WriteString(w, fmt.Sprintf("Header: %s", r.Header))` confirmed that _Authorization:[]_ map is empty and there is no _REMOTE_USER_ in that header. I'm stuck. (And there are reasons that I cannot discuss here that force me to use fcgi.)

Comment: Your attempt to use `r.BasicAuth()` is incorrect simply because reading the `REMOTE_USER` CGI variable means *the authentication is expected to be performed by the web server,* and you have no control over it. So what you need is to just correctly read the value of this variable. I have provided an answer on how to do that.

Comment: It doesn't look like `REMOTE_USER` is used in the fcgi package. I would have the webserver doing the auth put it in a header or an `HTTP_REMOTE_USER` variable.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks for clarification. Though modifying the webserver to work around an issue in go is not too appealing.

Comment: I don't think it's too big a deal. IIRC from the CGI days, I had a number of systems that would only use `HTTP_REMOTE_USER`, or some other custom variable. Assigning it after authentication was par for the course.

Comment: Go 1.9 will do it: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.9#net/http/fcgi

Comment: Go 1.9 is out and indeed it does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer (as of go version 1.4.2) is that go currently does not support the transfer of CGI variable REMOTE_USER.

Comment: Verified with Go 1.5 under Linux/amd64, Apache2 2.4.10 + `mod_fcgid` + `mod_auth_basic` + `mod_authz_user`

Answer (score 2):

Go 1.9 will expose cgi environment variables. As seen in this closed ticket:

https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/40012

Comment: Go 1.9 is out and it does expose `REMOTE_USER` indeed.

Answer (score 1):

While `@JimB` is correct on that you're wrong in your approach, I'll answer the question as stated.

The `net/http/fcgi` package uses the machinery of `net/http/cgi` to populate an instance of `http.Request`—which is passed to your handler—with "parameters" (key/value pairs) submitted by the webserver during the FastCGI session (call).
This is done [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fcgi/child.go#L261).

Now if you'll inspect [the relevant bit of the `net/http/cgi` code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/cgi/child.go#L52), you'll see that the variables which are not mapped to specific dedicated fields of `http.Request` [get converted to HTTP "headers"](https://golang.org/src/net/http/cgi/child.go#L82).

This means, <s>your code should be able to access the variable you need using something like</s>

```
ruser := r.Header.Get("Remote-User")
```

**Update 2015-12-02:** the reseach performed by `@JimB` and the OP showed that there's apparently no way to read the `REMOTE_USER` variable under FastCGI.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Actually, looking at the cgi/fcgi code now, I don't think REMOTE_USER will get transferred into the Go request at all. Only a few specific variables, and those starting with `HTTP_` are added to the headers.

Comment: @kostix: I have checked and falsified `r.Header.Get("Remote-User")`. That does not work, at least not in golang version 1.4.2 (pgk of OpenBSD 5.8). (As I mentioned in my original question (Quote: "To debug, I printed the output of r.Header").)
@JimB: I think you are right. Golang does not transfer REMOTE_USER into the go request.

Comment: @user208383, too bad. I'd consder this a bug. Sorry for misleading you with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [core change](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/40012/) to the fcgi package is in review and is close to being merged. If it's no longer relevant to you, hopefully it will be useful to others.